# AJAX login - getting errors from action file but submit on submit?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post, authentication

I'm working on simple Ajax login form.

Just two fields, login & password:

```
<form id="login-form" action="/login.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
   <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Log in" />
</form>
```

Then I set them as variables in login.php file:

```
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];

   if(!username_exists_in_my_database()) 
     // HOWTO: ajax displays 'Username doesn't exist next to username field
   if(username_exists_and_password_is_ok) 
     // HOWTO: NO AJAX, just send the form so my custom function logs the user
     // login($username);
```

How to display erros from AJAX for my form and submit it normally without ajax? Will JSON be secure enough for this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can send a json with an error without problems, and redirect the user on succesful login (and store his SESSION/COOKIE).

```
if(!username_exists_in_my_database()) 
     {
         header("Content-type: application/json");
         echo json_encode(array('error'=>'no such user'));
         die();
     } 

   if(username_exists_and_password_is_ok) 
     login($username);

function login($name){
   // store session etc
   header('Location: /index.php'); // redirect on succesful login
}
```

Comment: This is perfect too, but I'm not sure how to grab these json errors to front-end, I guess using "error" function for $.ajax?

Comment: oops, answered in the comment section _below_ )

Comment: you won't receive an error in $.ajax, as the data has been transmitted anyway. You'll check your received json data and check it for an error message, like $.ajax(...,complete: function(data){ if(data.error) alert("error occured"); }

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this, one I do a lot, is to return a `JSON` object, containing a `success` and a `errors`.

The `JSON` would look like this:

```
{
    "success": false
    "errors": ["Username doesn't exist next to username field"]
}
```

Then on the form successfully submitting, in jQuery you can check the `success` parameter, and if unsuccessful, display the `error` message.

In php:

```
$errors = [];
$success = false;
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(!username_exists_in_my_database()) 
    $errors[] = "Username doesn't exist next to username field";
    $success = false;

header('Content-type: application/json');
return json_encode(array("errors" => $errors, "success" => $success));
```

To display the errors, the following jQuery should be handy:

```
$form = $(this);
$.ajax({
    url: ...
    success: function(result) {
        if (!result.success) {
            if ($form.find('error').size() == 0) {
                $error_msg = $('<div class="error"></div>');
                $form.prepend($error_msg;
            }
            $error_msg.html(result.error).show();
        } else {
            $form.find('error').hide().remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: OK I got that, but how do I display these errors (or do any other actions like fading in things etc.) in front-end? :)

Comment: $.post('/login.php',{...},function(data){
   $("#any_empty_selector").append("<b>Error logging in, sorry</b>");
});

Comment: @Jeremy Blalock, your latest snippet is excellent, it's almost exactly what I've been looking for, but there's one problem - both ifs are always true, so even if I submit totally correct form - it still creates the error div and tris to assign the error (doesn't work as the error is empty). Any ideas why is that happening (also there's one ')' missing after $error_msg).